# Apexcharts. Annotation is behind labels

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

How can I do the annotation of a sticker over the Y axis?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2usqY.png)

I tried to use the following code, but it does not work.

```
annotations: {
                        position: "front",
                        yaxis: [
                            {
                                y: curentPrice,
                                borderColor: "#00C282",
                                offsetX: 15,
                                label: {
                                    borderColor: "#00C282",
                                    offsetX: 40,
                                    offsetY: 8,
                                    textAnchor: "middle",
                                    style: {
                                        color: "#fff",
                                        background: "#00C282",
                                        cssClass: "apexcharts-custom-annotation",
                                        padding: {
                                            left: 0,
                                            right: 4,
                                            top: 0,
                                            bottom: 0,
                                        },
                                    },
                                    text: curentPrice,
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
```

```
<style scoped>
.apexcharts-custom-annotation{
    z-index: 100000 !important;
}
</style>
```